# Value of an ITIL certification for a developer

Tags: career, certification, itil

I am having a hard time finding information on this, as most people looking at this cert are not developers.

I have an opportunity to get the cert for free with paid classroom time.

What, if any, is the value of this certification for a developer with no immediate plans to move in to project management?

Comment: Any certification is valuable if it's what you want to do. If you want to spend the rest of your career mired in obstructionist paperwork as you reminisce about the career of actually building useful software that could have been… then yes.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a project management question. ITIL isn't a project management cert, and the value is going to be highly personal, not general to either profession.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) ITIL is not a project management cert, (b) the value of a cert is highly personal and not relevant to either profession as a whole, (c) it doesn't ask about a practial project management problem as described in [ask].

Comment: Fair enough. I tried to write as generally as possible and left my opinions in the comments. I know at my organization ITIL certs are fairly common amongst PM's, so I'd say it not being a PM cert is debatable, which is why I brought up the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer: The certification is valuable**

If your employer is paying for it, it may be a possibility that they compete or bid on work/contracts that require professionals with the ITIL certification.  If this is the case, this could open doors for you in the future in technical leadership roles.  Although you mentioned that you are not currently interested in management, the ITIL cert will give you additional insight into how those processes interact between IT services and the business.

Answer (score 1):

ITIL is into IT Services Management. Since you are a developer it will not make much difference. But ITIL and those concepts better to be aware of them since you an IT professional. Might help in your career one day.

Answer (score 0):

Methodology certifications are "icing on the cake" for hiring. They definitely come second to experience, but better than nothing.

Have a look at some local job ads for positions you may want to go into and see if they mention it as a desirable or a requirement. If not, I wouldn't worry about it.

There are a million and one IT certifications and very few of them equate to anything more than a day or two in a casual classroom. That's precisely the weight that is given to them - a few days worth of effort. It's better than nothing, but not by that much.

Comment: I am a developer. I don't have much interest in the management side at this point, and just want to be the best developer I can be. I won't be job hunting for a couple years, at least.

Comment: I'd spend your money on something more useful then. It's not going to benefit you to get the certification.

Comment: It's not my money. It's paid for by my employer.

Comment: Up to you then and how you value your time (or whether you want the free meals that come with the training) - I've accepted many free things I didn't want simply because they were free. It won't help your career to have it though.

Answer (score 0):

ITIL is the defacto standard for service management. Historically, its main focus has been on operations. If you are a developer in a DevOps project, ITIL will give you a much better understanding of the Ops side. As a project manager of a DevOps project, I would choose specialists/team members who are knowledgeable on both sides. Also, there are companies that require (hired) staff to be ITIL certified (i.e. automotive industry).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).